# When a cron job is set to "run every 5 minutes", does it run every 5 minutes from the moment it's added?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, cron-task

When a cron job is set to "run every 5 minutes", does it run **a)** every 5 minutes from the moment it's added, or **b)** every 5 minutes from the zero-minute mark?

For example, if a 5-minute cron job is added at 10:17, does it run as per schedule **a)**:

```
10:22
10:27
10:32
etc..
```

or schedule **b)**:

```
10:20
10:25
10:30
etc...
```

?

Comment: A cron task should run as per `schedule b` relative to midnight, no relative to the time it was created

Comment: @MarkBaker: Could you please add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*/5` in the minutes field means "from first to last, every 5 minutes", so it will start running at 0 minutes past the hour and every 5 minutes thereafter.